# How fix bug with composer install --disable-phar

Tags: php, centos, composer-php

I'm have php version 5.6, and I need to install composer for my project. I'm installing using these commands:

```
 curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
 php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php
```

I'm getting this error message:

```
Some settings on your machine make Composer unable to work properly.
Make sure that you fix the issues listed below and run this script again:

The phar extension is missing.
Install it or recompile php without --disable-phar
```

Comment: Sorry for pure english.

Comment: Do you know what a `phar` extension is?

Comment: How did i test exist phar?

Comment: Look at a `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` report.

Comment: It is true /etc/php.d/20-phar.ini?

Answer (score 1):

The error tells you that you have to enable or install the extension for `.phar` files.

Because you didn't give any information about your system, OS and so on, there is nothing more I can do to help point you into the correct direction. In general it's unlikely that you have to recompile PHP, you have to search the source of your current PHP version how to obtain or enable said extension.